# How to set the number of decimals for a number value in SurveyJS

Tags: surveyjs

By using the type Text and inputType Number, a question where a number is expected can be defined within SurveyJS.

From the documentation I don't find an option to indicate the numberOfDecimals for a number field.

Is this option available?
To be done by a Regex?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

We don't have this property out of the box. You can introduce [this property](https://surveyjs.io/survey-creator/documentation/property-grid#add-custom-properties-to-the-property-grid) on the text question level and then round your value based on this property by using [survey.onValueChanging](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/documentation/api-reference/survey-data-model#onValueChanging) event.

```js
//Add the property into text question
Survey.Serializer.addProperty("text", {
      name: "numberOfDecimals:number",
      default: 3,
      dependsOn: "inputType",
      visibleIf: (obj: any) => { return obj.inputType === "number"; },
      category: "general"
});

const json = {
  elements: [
    { type: "text", name: "q1", inputType: "number", numberOfDecimals: 1}
  ]
}

function SurveyComponent() {
    const survey = new Survey.Model(json);
    survey.onValueChanging.add((sender, options) => {
      const q = options.question;
      if(q.numberOfDecimals === undefined || !options.value) return;
      options.value = options.value.toFixed(q.numberOfDecimals);
    });
    survey.onComplete.add((sender, options) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(sender.data, null, 3));
    });
    return (<SurveyReact.Survey model={survey} />);
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("surveyElement"));
root.render(<SurveyComponent />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/survey-core@1.9.97/survey.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/survey-react-ui@1.9.97/survey-react-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/survey-core@1.9.97/defaultV2.min.css" />

<div id="surveyElement"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for you answer!
Will this numberOfDecimals be added to one of the next product releases?

Comment: If we add all possible functionality that our customers/developers asked us to implement then it will be impossible to use the library. This functionality is important for you and probably some other developers. If it is requested by many others, we will add it. You can extend our libraries in many different ways, from model to rendering. We can't recognize our libraries when some of our customers sent us their web apps.